# Wrap horizontal scrollable div with parent overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, css, animation, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I have found one code on Codepen that I liked so I want to introduce it on my website. [Link to codepen](http://codepen.io/ssg1292/pen/wgmKax)

The code move the full html and body to the left in order to show the next horizontal page with a particle/bubble animation. But it also move the other divs.

**What I want?**

Wrap this code inside a div so when the button is clicked generate a scroll but only inside the div, and the other divs are visible.

**What problems I have faced?**

When I create a div with a overflow: hidden and inside another div with overflow-x: scroll, I get my wanted result, but the animation of the bubbles/particles dissapear and sometimes fail getting the scroll ofset position.

```
                $('html, body').stop();
            $html.stop().animate({
                scrollLeft: target.offset().left
            }, 1700,'easeOutQuint');
```

This code is the responsible of the movement, if I try to do it from the div, the funcionality crashes.

Here is a Jsfiddle of a test case.
[JsFiddle link demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eu8j6cwk/1/)

Thank you very much.
Greetings.

Comment: That CodePen example has 7 Scrollax scripts included.

Comment: The important one for me is the particles movement on scroll left.